# Trouble Displaying Decimals

Tags: java, javafx, numbers, int, double

I am just starting making small applications and I was trying to make an application that shows the user now much interest he/she would get after a year. My code looks like this http://pastebin.com/K1LuSZsq and my display has three buttons, the first is the place where you input the amount of money you have, the second is the % intrest and the third is the output. The problem I am having is that it is not calculating the (intrest/100), and just displaying 0: http://prntscr.com/42tnr1. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code you have

```
double test = original/100;
```

where `original` is an `int`

An `int divided by and 100 (also an`int`) will give you an`int`

In other word, the result will be converted to an `int`

e.g

```
result = 5 / 100;
```

The result will be 0